# How can I implement from xml file layout inside the App using Android studio?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm beginner in Android. I want implement this graphic layout into an Android App:
[image]

How can I generate `xml` to implement the layout on the picture in Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below is your desired layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:weightSum="3"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#C3C3C3"
    android:layout_height="0dp">

    <ImageView
        android:background="@color/black_color"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:background="#FFC90E"
    android:layout_height="0dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="this is text view which is scrollable"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

> The total weight sum of the parent linearlayout is 3 and 1 is assigned to linear layout that contain imageview and 2 is to scroll view you can change the height of these two views by changing the values of 1 and 2 but the sum should not increase more then 3

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="sample text" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```